# VBA to convert a query to a table

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create some code that will place the results of a query into a table, can anyone help me out with this?

Currently, a coded button will copy all the information from a CSV which contains more than 255 columns and place it inside a linked table named tblImport. Next the code will create a query including all of the data from tblImport, now i want to be able to convert this query into a new local table.

```html
Private Sub cmdImportExcel_Click()
'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tblRawTestData", "C:\Users\jacklythgoe\documents\Access\Test Analyzer\data\TestResultsCopy.csv", True, Range:="TestResultsCopy!A:C"


   ' Requires reference to Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library.
 
   Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim testResultsWorkSheet As Worksheet, strFile As String


   ' Set up the File Dialog.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fDialog
 
      ' Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
             
      ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select which file you want to load"
 
      ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Text File", "*.csv"
 
      ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
 
         'Loop through each file selected and add it to our list box.
        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems

         Next
         
      End If
   End With
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, tableName:="tblImport", FileName:="C:\Users\jacklythgoe\Documents\Access\Test Analyzer\data\TestResultsCopy.csv", HasFieldNames:=False
'DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImport", FileName:="C:\MyData.csv", HasFieldNames:=True

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qDef As DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qDef = db.CreateQueryDef("ImportQuery")
qDef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblImport"
qDef.Close
db.Close
Set qDef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need to link it first? You can directly import a CSV file to an msaccess table.

Comment: As i said there are more than 255 columns in the CSV, so i had to take this route to get what i needed.

Comment: If you can think of another option to turn the linked table to a local table on the press of the button. I have tried vba to copy and paste the table as a local but that didnt work.

Comment: But msaccess is limited to 255 columns per table, see here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c#:~:text=General&text=2%20gigabytes%2C%20minus%20the%20space,be%20as%20large%20as%202GB.

Comment: bruh i know. But i solved that with the above code

Comment: Im asking how do i turn it into a local table, or  from query to a table

Comment: I understand that, but the local table can't exceed 255 columns. Anyhow, assuming that   it will accept it, have you tried `select * into newtable from oldlinkedtable` syntax?

Comment: The above code is resolved that issue as i have all the columns inside. And for that code block, how would i implement that into the VBA

Comment: So you mean select * into, called from VBA? Not that difficult but it wouldn't fit into comments, and the question is not accepting answers. Try docmd.runsql, but if it doesn't work post another question

Comment: If you go to my account there is another question. As this is a duplicated question apparently

Comment: I did this, and it says record is too big as an error

Comment: That is the 255 column limit. I don't think you can overcome that